# How to connect a earth leakage detection GFCI/ELCB?

Tags: electrical, gfci

My specifications are as follows:

- 2 in phase 120V lines
- 1 Neutral
- 1 Ground

So, I should use a 240V GFCI, right ?

This is the one I plan to use: [Heavy Duty - High Power GFCIs](http://www.trci.net/products/shock-shield/user-attachables/high-power-gfci) part no- 23250 003-1 GFCI

So, connections would be connecting one 120V line to the line wire on gfci, 2nd line wire to the second line wire on GFCI and neutral to neutral and ground to ground.

IS that correct ? Or, am I going wrong anywhere ?

Answer (score 1):

You should wire it according to the [manufacturers documentation](http://www.trci.net/media/76173/cci_safety_products_brochure_34.pdf).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your plan will work *provided* the GFCI has two hots and a neutral -- I cannot tell from the documentation your link provides if it is hot/hot/neutral/(I presume ground?) or hot/neutral/ground.

If you can't use that, a "spa panel" with a two-pole GFCI breaker of the appropriate rating will work as a substitute -- it will need to be hard-wired into the AC line though, as opposed to being wired into the cord as I presume the unit you linked is.